# How to get index value of a scrollview at certain position?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview like below with V as an overlay and it acts like a pointer:

```
   V
 [ 0 ] , [ 1 ] , [ 2 ] , [ 3 ] , [ 4 ] , [ 5 ] 
   ^
```

When I scroll, I would like to print the value or index that is in the current pointer.
Eg. scroll until [2] and it will print "2".

```
   V
 [ 2 ] , [ 3 ] , [ 4 ] , [ 5 ] 
   ^
```

Could you guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: SwiftUI is pretty limited in terms of reading a scroll position (despite the questionably-named `ScrollViewReader`, which really does the opposite). This may be a problem better-solved with UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using offset for this. Set a fixed width for a column, then we can calculate the offset for each column.